# Odds of getting equal amount of each color in a bag of M&Ms

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assume they were mass produced by Mars in equal amounts of all 6 colors.  Assume a bag contains 54 M&Ms.  What is the probability that you get a bag with EXACTLY 9 of each color?

Comment: What have you tried?  If $54$ seems big, try to solve the same problem with a smaller multiple of six.  $6$ itself, perhaps.  Or $12$.

Comment: You mean a smaller multiple of 6.

Comment: @A.Pongrácz  Indeed.  Strange error, really.  (edited now).

Comment: It is worth figuring out the probability distribution yourself at least once, but if you want the name of it it is called the multinomial distribution.

Comment: By the way, the colors aren't actually equally likely, which means that the probability you'll find is an overestimate.

Answer (score 3):

Compute the chance of getting exactly $9$ of the first color with $54$ draws with replacement.  You have $45$ left that are of $5$ colors.  Compute the chance of getting exactly $9$ of the second color within this group of $45$.  Keep going.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is partially in response to the comment by Michael Lugo above, and partially just a slightly more in depth answer.

Since Mars created equal numbers of each M&M, suppose they created $n$ of each color. You are choosing 54 M&Ms from the collection of $6n$ M&Ms that were created. But, you are looking for the outcome where you have exactly 9 of each color. So, that probability would be:

$$\begin{align*}\dfrac{\dbinom{n}{9}^6}{\dbinom{6n}{54}} & = \dfrac{\dfrac{n^6(n-1)^6(n-2)^6(n-3)^6(n-4)^6(n-5)^6(n-6)^6(n-7)^6(n-8)^6}{(9!)^6}}{\dfrac{6n(6n-1)\cdots (6n-53)}{54!}} \\ & = \dfrac{54!}{(9!)^6}\dfrac{n^{54}+O(n^{53})}{(6n)^{54} + O(n^{53})} \\ & = \dfrac{54!}{(9!)^6}\cdot \dfrac{1}{6^{54}}\left(\dfrac{n^{54}+O(n^{53})}{n^{54}+O(n^{53})}\right)\end{align*}$$

Taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ gets the answer that callculus gave. But, for small $n$, the probability is actually greater that you will get 9 of each color. But this is a decreasing function of $n$. If $n=9$, the probability is 1. Once $n>10000$, the estimate callculus's approach gives is accurate within two decimal places (to $10^{-7}$).

Answer (score 0):

You have a very big mountain M&M´s. The mountain contains  6 colors of M&M´s, with (approximately) equal proportion. If you pick some M&M´s we can assume that the probability of picking a specific color doesn´t change since the population is very large.

Therefore the probability to pick one color  of M&M is constant $\frac16$. For this case you can use the multinomial distribution. The probability to pick exactly $9$ M&M´s from each color is

$P(X_1=9, ..., X_6=9)=\frac{54!}{9!\cdot 9!\cdot 9!\cdot 9!\cdot 9!\cdot 9!}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^9\cdot \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^9\cdot\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^9\cdot\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^9\cdot\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^9\cdot\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{9}$

$=\frac{54!}{9!\cdot 9!\cdot 9!\cdot 9!\cdot 9!\cdot 9!}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{54}\approx 0.00009651=9.651\cdot 10^{-5}$

You see the probability is not very large. The situation might  looks like below 
[image]